# How to deal with multiple connections from the same IP?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

So, I have the following code that catches a new connection, then hands that connection to its own thread to handle the client.

```
    private void loop(int port) {
        // Opens a port for connections.
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server running in port " + port);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

        // Listens for a connection
    while (onlineState == true && serverSocket != null) {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();

            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println(clientSocket.getInetAddress() + " has connected to the port " + clientSocket.getPort());

                new Thread(new SocketThread(clientSocket)).run();

                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

So, my problem here is that when I try to connect with multiple client apps to the server, the server only seems to either accept one connection at any given time. The client itself is a very simple application of the basic tutorial: it simply repeats any string that the server sends to it.

I have two guesses as to why this is happening: a) there's something wrong with my handling code, b) it's because both connections are from the same IP.

However, neither case is a good thing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (Except everything)

Comment: Different connections from the same IP address will have a different source port.

Comment: are you wanting to close the clientSocket right after starting the thread? Maybe it seems to only have one at a time because the previous connection is closed right before the new connection begins.

Comment: You don't need to create a new Socket, you just need to call accept(). In general it is poor practice to initialize variables that are assigned on the very next line. In this case it's not just poor practice, it is an FD leak. And you certainly should *not* close it in the accept loop. The thread should, close it when it gets end-of-stream.

Comment: Basically, I added the close() to check if it would accept the other connection even then. But, the problem was in the run() bit of the code, as can be seen in the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You want to call `start()`, not `run()` on your `Thread` object. The difference is that `start()` actually goes and does threaded stuff, like running it in the background. Calling `run()` from where you call it there will handle all the client communication right there, inline. That's why you only ever accept one connection - you won't accept any more until you've serviced that client.
2. You don't want to call `clientSocket.close()` in your main thread. In your implementation of `SocketThread`, call `clientSocket.close()` at the end of your `run()` method, probably inside a `finally` block.

Also, does `SocketThread` extend `Thread`? If so, you don't need `new Thread()`, just do

```
new SocketThread(clientSocket).start();
```

If it doesn't extend `Thread`, why not name it `SocketRunnable` or `ClientRunnable` or something like that.

Comment: I actually named it like that because I want to know from the name what it is that I want the class to do. But, it seems that this "incorrectness" has actually resulted in me gaining new helpful knowledge on the topic.